# creating a function that takes the key and value of a dictionary to create a new value

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm trying to come up with a simple function that takes two inputs (dict key and dict value) and returns a new value for the dictionary. And I want it to be able to be called for a broad number of cases, not just one specific instance.

sample input would look like this:

```
dict = {1: 11, 2: 12, 3: 13, 4: 14, 5: 15}
```

and the output would look like this:

```
new_dict = {1: 12, 2: 14, 3: 16, 4: 18, 5: 20}
```

I was trying to use something like a dict comprehension (`new_dict = {k:v + k, v in dict.items()}`, which obviously does not work), but not sure if this is the right approach and couldn't figure out how to get that addition part to work correctly. What's a clean/simple way of going about this to be able to work with a bunch of different inputs?

Comment: You didn't get the syntx exactly right for the dictionary comprehension.  It should read like a `for` loop `{k: k+v for k, v in d.items()}`.  Also, don't use the name `dict`, there's already a built-in function with that name.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're just missing the `for` in your list comprehension.

```
new_dict = {k:v + k for k, v in dict.items()}
```

Comment: You mean 'dict comprehension'?

Answer (score 0):

First, `dict` is already [used for instantiating dictionaries](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict), and you shouldn't use it in the manner you did.

Second, you are missing important part in comprehension and that is `for`.

That's why it didn't work.

Heres how it works:

```
a = {1: 11, 2: 12, 3: 13, 4: 14, 5: 15}

print {k: k+v for k, v in a.items()}
# {1: 12, 2: 14, 3: 16, 4: 18, 5: 20}
```

Comment: `dict` is not a [keyword](https://docs.python.org/3.3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#keywords).  You can overwrite it (though you obviously shouldn't without good reason)

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
for i in dict:
    new_dict[i] = dict[i] + i
```